# In windows server 2008, application's login form is not getting activated

Tags: forms, windows-server-2008

My application is developed in C# windows. On executing the application in Windows XP, login form is getting activated properly and focus is set to UserName_TextBox. But in windows server 2008, login form is not getting activated. only after clicking on the login form, its getting activated.

I have tried code like...

```
this.Activate();
this.ActiveControl = tbUserName;
```

or

```
this.Select();
```

Set the form as TopMost..etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not the active application on the system, then you cannot activate it.  Image how annoying it would be to a user if an application was able to switch to itself while they were using another program!